# java.util.logging: file handler with append and count properties

Tags: java, logging

Can I use **java.util.logging.FileHandler.count** and **java.util.logging.FileHandler.append** properties together?

My requirement is that, I want to append the log messages to a log file till it reaches a limit and then cycle through to the next file.

I tried using following properties:

```
count = 3
append = true
pattern = xyz_%g.log
```

but for every run, instead of appending, xyz_0.log gets copied to xyz_1.log and xyz_0.log gets the whole new contents.

Comment: What value have you supplied for the limit parameter?

Comment: java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 1024000 and general log file size is 4-8 KB

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to combine them.
Just look at the constructors in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html